# Truncating text in an ASP.NET GridView but displaying a tooltip preview on hover?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

In an ASP.NET GridView is it possible to truncate the displayed text but yet keep the whole string so that it can be displayed in a tooltip on hover over?

I have a code behind function written as follows:

```
public static string TruncateString(string stringToTruncate, int length)
{
   return stringToTruncate.Length > length ?
      stringToTruncate.Substring(0, length) + "..." : 
      stringToTruncate;
}
```

Switching to the .aspx page I have a GridView created thereon. This is bound to the contents of a custom object which is filled from the results of a sproc.

For the purposes of this let's assume the field is called BigNVarCharField, autogeneration of columns is turned off and the usual GridView markup is in place.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="BigNVarCharField" HeaderText="Big field preview" Visible="true">
```

I thought that I should be able to do something like use the DataFormatString attribute thus but it doesn't seem to be working

```
DataFormatString = '<%#HelperFunctions.TruncateString(Convert.ToString(Eval("BigNVarCharField")))%>'
```

I don't want to truncate it in the database or the business logic as I want to be able to display it in a tooltip on hover over the column in question.

The site is already using jQuery so that can be used for the tooltip if needs be.

EDIT: 2011-04-23 How it worked out finally

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Big field preview">
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBigNVarCharField" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BigNVarCharField") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblBigNVarCharField" runat="server" Text='<%# HelperFunctions.TruncateString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BigNVarCharField").ToString(), 50)%>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("BigNVarCharField")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Marking Chad's one as the accepted answer as that was what steered me in the correct direction.

Comment: Re downvote: what's not useful about it? Leave a comment and at least have the courage of your convictions (and in the process allow me to improve the question!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert this to a template field then insert your as label text.  I would probably use the row databound event to handle the logic but you may be able to accomplish it in the markup.

The [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) is good for numbers and dates but will not do what you are looking for.

Comment: This sounds promising, but would there be any chance you could expand on it a small bit?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put the truncated text in the table cell.  And then put the full version within a hidden element inside the same cell.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    The quick brown fox...
    <span class="hidden">
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    </span>    
  </td>
</tr>
```

Use CSS/jQuery to get the effect that you want when you hover over the cell.

```
$('table').delegate('td:has(span)', 'mouseenter mouseleave', function() {

   //your code goes here.

});
```

I realize I gave you an incomplete solution.  It really depends on how you want to display your tooltips.  CSS and some jQuery is all that needed, check out these links to finish it off.

- http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/12/simple-tooltip-for-huge-number-of-elements
- http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/12/using-settimeout-to-delay-showing-event-delegation-tooltips

Comment: Thanks for that, however I'm using a GridView in ASP.NET and I was hoping not to have to go after the raw HTML in this fashion. Is there any more ASP.NET centric way of doing the first part?

Comment: By ASP.NET centric way, you mean can you write server-side code that will generate the HTML, CSS and JS necessary to do what you are asking... there may be kind of plugin but ASP.NET out of the box can't do it... write some JS, you'll enjoy it :)

Comment: In a nutshell, yes that's what I mean. I needed to get something done and working in the shortest timeframe possible hence my request for ASP.NET-centric ways of doing this. I've edited the original question above to reflect the final solution and as Chad was the one to point me in direction of the final solution I had to award the answer to him - sorry and thanks for your help.